# Xcode15 B/BL out of range 166921072(max+/-128MB)

Tags: xcode15

Xcode15  B/BL out of range 166921072(max+/-128MB) to 'grrenderbufferStorageMultisample'

After upgrading to Xcode15, I encountered the following error during compilation. The old version of xcode14.3 did not have this issue, and I also attempted to improve the following
Other Linker Flags - ld64
But it still reported an error. I would like to ask if you have encountered the same problem. There is a post on this website that states that Flutter also reported an error when running. He added - ld64, but it still did not solve my problem

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?